# Create image and text multipage pdf file from scrollview in Swift

Tags: ios

I have tried some stackoverflow alternatives but text and images are not rendered, only the pdf pages are created in the pdf file. Below my logic for iOS Swift 4. I appreciate any help, thanks in advance. Relatório is my scrollview and page type is A4. Below logic is part of a function after the scrollview is created.

```
let pdfData = NSMutableData()
let scrollHeigt = self.Relatorio.contentSize.height
let rawNumberOfPages = scrollHeigt/CGFloat(841.8)
let numberOfPages = Int(ceil(rawNumberOfPages))
var pageNumber = Int()
let pageSize = CGSize(width:595.2, height:841.8)
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)
let pdfContext:CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
repeat 
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:pageSize.width, height:pageSize.height), nil)
    if pageNumber < 1 
    {
        self.Relatorio.layer.render(in: pdfContext) 
    } 
    else 
    {
        if pageNumber >= 1 
        {
            let offsetForScroll = CGFloat(pageNumber*842)
            self.Relatorio.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:offsetForScroll), animated: false)
            pdfContext.translateBy(x:0, y:offsetForScroll)
            self.Relatorio.layer.render(in: pdfContext)
         }
    }
    pageNumber = pageNumber + 1
}
while pageNumber < numberOfPages

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

//  Save to Document Directory.

let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
pdfData.write(toFile: "\(documentsPath)/new.pdf", atomically: true)

return (pdfData,"\(documentsPath)/new.pdf")
```

Comment: any update on this